# How to use AWS CDK to look up existing ApiGateway

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am using AWS CDK to build my lambda, and I would like to register endpoints from the lambda's CDK stack.

I found I can get an existing ApiGateway construct using fromRestApiId(scope, id, restApiId)
([documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.RestApi.html#static-fromwbrrestwbrapiwbrattributesscope-id-attrsspan-classapi-icon-api-icon-experimental-titlethis-api-element-is-experimental-it-may-change-without-noticespan))

So currently this works well:

```
    //TODO how to look up by ARN instead of restApiId and rootResourceId??
    const lambdaApi = apiGateway.LambdaRestApi
                                .fromRestApiAttributes(this, generateConstructName("api-gateway"), {
                                    restApiId: <API_GATEWAY_ID>,
                                    rootResourceId: <API_GATEWAY_ROOT_RESOURCE_ID>,
                                });

    const lambdaApiIntegration = new apiGateway.LambdaIntegration(lambdaFunction,{
        proxy: true,
        allowTestInvoke: true,
    })

    const root = lambdaApi.root;

    root.resourceForPath("/v1/meeting/health")
        .addMethod("GET", lambdaApiIntegration);
```

But I would like to deploy to many AWS accounts, and many regions. I don't want to have to hardcode the **API_GATEWAY_ID** or **API_GATEWAY_ROOT_RESOURCE_ID** for each account-region pair.

Is there a more generic way to get the existing ApiGateway construct, (e.g. by name or ARN)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is ARN for Api Gateway, I don't see one. Are you referring to `arn:aws:execute-api:region:accountId:apiId/*` that we refer in IAM policies? it still has api-id part of it. so, whatever we choose to parameterize the CDK code with stack imports or environment variables or stack inputs, we have to choose to include api-id anyway.

Comment: Great point :} 
I found this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/arn-format-reference.html, 
but maybe since there is no direct ARN, that is why we cannot look up the existing API construct by ARN.

Comment: Mostly places, I have exported api id from CloudFormation/CDK and imported into other stacks/cdk where it is used. let me know if you want me to write up an answer with some details.

Comment: That would be amazing if you could write something on exports!

We need to do this in other CDK stacks where we want to reference an export of a group of resources (export a group of security groups, and the CDK can reference the export by name, instead of the unique security groups by account/region -unique names).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lets take a simple Api with one resource

```
const restApi = new apigw.RestApi(this, "my-api", {
  restApiName: `my-api`,
});
const mockIntegration = new apigw.MockIntegration();
const someResource = new apigw.Resource(this, "new-resource", {
  parent: restApi.root,
  pathPart: "somePath",
  defaultIntegration: mockIntegration,
});
someResource.addMethod("GET", mockIntegration);
```

Lets assume we want use this api and resource in another stack, we first need to export

```
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, `my-api-export`, {
  exportName: `my-api-id`,
  value: restApi.restApiId,
});

new cdk.CfnOutput(this, `my-api-somepath-export`, {
  exportName: `my-api-somepath-resource-id`,
  value: someResource.resourceId,
});
```

Now we need to import in new stack

```
const restApi = apigw.RestApi.fromRestApiAttributes(this, "my-api", {
  restApiId: cdk.Fn.importValue(`my-api-id`),
  rootResourceId: cdk.Fn.importValue(`my-api-somepath-resource-id`),
});
```

and simply add additional resources and methods.

```
const mockIntegration = new apigw.MockIntegration();
new apigw.Resource(this, "new-resource", {
  parent: restApi.root,
  pathPart: "new",
  defaultIntegration: mockIntegration,
});
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what we need!
Thank you Balu!

Comment: How do you get the URL for the imported API to show as an output ?  
When we get an existing api, "restApi.url" doesn't exist.

Comment: @MehradEslami There is no url returned by cdk/cloudformation [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#aws-resource-apigateway-restapi-return-values) is list of returned values. You can always build your own url with api-id

Comment: Thanks Balu, created the url using api id and path.

Comment: Thanks so much, Balu. You helped to save a lot of my time