# How to use AWS CDK to look up existing ApiGateway (Python )

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

Hi I am doing same as of this question but this is in javascript.

reference of question [How to use AWS CDK to look up existing ApiGateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65706835/how-to-use-aws-cdk-to-look-up-existing-apigateway)

And my python code look like this
**exporting resource**

```
 cdk.CfnOutput(self, "my-api", export_name = 'my-api-id', value=my_api.rest_api_id)
 cdk.CfnOutput(self, "my-resource-api", export_name='my-resource-api-id',value=my_api.rest_api_root_resource_id)
```

**importing  in new stack:**

```
my_new_api = RestApi.from_rest_api_attributes(
            self, "new-resource",
            rest_api_id=cdk.Fn.import_value('my-api-id'),
            root_resource_id=cdk.Fn.import_value('my-resource-api-id')
        )
```

adding additional resources

```
mini_sets = my_new_api.root.add_resource("mini")
    mini_sets.add_method(
        http_method='GET',
        authorizer=mini_sets_api_authorizer
    )
```

*but after doing all this getting this error :*

**TypeError: unhashable type: 'collections.OrderedDict'**

**EDIT** full traceback of error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "samcli/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
  File "click/core.py", line 782, in main
  File "click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
  File "samcli/lib/iac/utils/helpers.py", line 55, in wrapper
  File "samcli/commands/_utils/iac_validations.py", line 79, in wrapped
  File "click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
  File "click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 174, in wrapped
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 141, in wrapped
  File "samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 42, in wrapped
  File "samcli/cli/main.py", line 90, in wrapper
  File "samcli/commands/local/start_api/cli.py", line 128, in cli
  File "samcli/commands/local/start_api/cli.py", line 204, in do_cli
  File "samcli/commands/local/lib/local_api_service.py", line 37, in __init__
  File "samcli/lib/providers/api_provider.py", line 37, in __init__
  File "samcli/lib/providers/api_provider.py", line 64, in _extract_api
  File "samcli/lib/providers/cfn_api_provider.py", line 64, in extract_resources
  File "samcli/lib/providers/cfn_api_provider.py", line 188, in _extract_cloud_formation_method
  File "samcli/lib/providers/cfn_api_provider.py", line 351, in resolve_resource_path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/_collections_abc.py", line 660, in get
  File "samcli/lib/iac/interface.py", line 469, in __getitem__
TypeError: unhashable type: 'collections.OrderedDict'
[45088] Failed to execute script __main__
```

Comment: What's the line that generates the error?

Comment: Why not just pass the ApiGateway construct across stacks? Are the stacks in different CDK apps?

Comment: @gshpychka when I run this   `sam-beta-cdk local start-api`  this error comes

Comment: @gshpychka  by architecture my app have diff stacks. but not sure what you are saying can you please give a little example of how I can do with  `ApiGateway construct across stacks` ?

Comment: @gshpychka sir am I doing anything wrong in this flow or missing something ?

Comment: you can pass the apigateway object from one stack to the other as an argument. Examples can be found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html

Comment: What's the line number that generates the error?

Comment: @gshpychka sir I have updated question with full traceback , on this command `sam-beta-cdk local start-api` it's happening .

Comment: What's `click/core.py`?

Comment: @gshpychka some library files of aws-cdk I think . Not in my project

Comment: @gshpychka sir tried to share  resource from  stack1 to stack2  getting this error    `jsii.errors.JSIIError: Cannot reference across apps. Consuming and producing stacks must be defined within the same CDK app.`

Comment: Why do you have multiple CDK apps?