# is this possible to extend api-gateway api's using python cdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

is this possible to get a api gateway using it's arn and then add more endpoints to it ? for example I have a api gateway and it's root path is '/path-one' and more api's are attached to it like  '/path-one/one' etc  not I want to get this api gateway using it's
**rest_api_root_resource_id** and then add new api like '/path-one/two' to same path . is this possible ? how i can achieve using python cdk

**FOR Example** as the same way we access lambda function using arn

```
 self.my_lambda = _lambda.Function.from_function_arn(self, "my-lambda", my_lambda_arn)
```

in same type of thing for api gateway I am finding. any help would be highly appericiated.

Comment: Yes. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65706835/how-to-use-aws-cdk-to-look-up-existing-apigateway) has a Typescript example. The Python CDK syntax follows the same pattern.

Comment: @fedonev facing some issue on python by doing this  this issues is opened on git-hub https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/20086 . is there any way to fix or do differently ?